# Linux Python Dogtail Update from Ubuntu to Red Hat - pyatspi libraries

Tags: linux, python

I am trying to update some python scripts that were written in Ubuntu using Assisstive Technologies to be used on a Red Hat platform. The original scripts used the "pyatspi" library for a number of functions, but this library is not available for our current version of Red Hat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server Release 5.2.0.4).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to use assisstive technologies features with perhaps another library for Red Hat or an additional approach as to how to be able to launch the software without using Assistive Technologies.

Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are several different rpm's for **python-at-spi** you might want to check. **python-at-spi** is another Assisstive Technology Python interface

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=at-spi-python&srodzaj=3